# Calculate subtotal, sales tax, and order total

Tags: c#

Okay, so I'm sure this has been asked before but I can't seem to find anything in relation. I'm trying to create an assignment for school. It's a lunch order menu where you can place your order. We have to calculate the subtotal, the sales tax, and the order total. I can't seem to figure out the right code to use and I'm not 100% sure on what to try here.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{

        decimal subtotal = 0m;
    decimal salesTax = 0m;
    decimal orderTotal = 0m; 
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rdoBurger.Checked = true;
        rdoPizza.Checked = true;
        rdoSalad.Checked = true;

    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void clearTotals()
    {

    }

    private void btnPlaceOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is RadioButton)
        {
            clearTotals();
        }
        if (rdoBurger.Checked)
        {

            decimal subtotal = 6.95m;
            subtotal = Convert.ToDecimal(lblSubtotal.Text);
        }
```

This is what I have but it's not showing the actual subtotal, it's still blank. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: lblSubtotal.Text = subtotal.ToString();

Comment: Post a **screenshot** of your interface so we can understand how you've got it setup.  This makes a difference because your variable names indicate you've ~probably~ used RadioButtons, which might be mutually exclusive depending on what container(s) they've been placed in.  So, depending on how you've set it up, you might be able to pick only one of those options at a time, or you might be able to have multiple items selected...

Comment: @Idle_Mind do you mean the gui? I'm not sure what you mean by interface. lblSubtotal is the name of the textbox.

Comment: GUI = Graphical User **Interface**...so the same thing as just Interface.  =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bad start.  This is more like what I'd expect to see:

```
    private void btnPlaceOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // only ONE of these can be checked, so "else if" is used
        if (rdoBurger.Checked)
        {
            subtotal = 6.95m;
        }
        else if (rdoPizza.Checked)
        {
            subtotal = 5.95m;
        }
        else if (rdoSalad.Checked)
        {
            subtotal = 4.95m;
        }

        // multiple of these could be checked, so only "if" is used
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            subtotal = subtotal + 100.00m; // whatever this item costs
        }
        if (checkBox2.Checked)
        {
            subtotal = subtotal + 4.99m; // whatever this item costs
        }
        if (checkBox3.Checked)
        {
            subtotal = subtotal + 10.99m; // whatever this item costs
        }

        // compute the tax and the total:
        salesTax = subtotal * 0.0775m;
        orderTotal = subtotal + salesTax;

        // output it to your labels/textboxes?
        lblSubtotal.Text = "$" + subtotal.ToString("F2");
        lblSalesTax.Text = "$" + salesTax.ToString("F2");
        lblOrderTotal.Text = "$" + orderTotal.ToString("F2");
    }
```

Comment: I am now trying to create a clear totals method. I'm not sure how I would do that with multiple choices. I need it to clear the sales tax, subtotal, and order total.

Comment: Just use `lblXXX.Text = "";` to clear out the controls.   To uncheck a checkbox, use `checkBox1.Checked = false;`.

Comment: I'd have to see your updated code to check, but my example includes the add ons in the computed sales tax.

Comment: If you want it to update **immediately** when a selection is changed, then wire up the [CheckedChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) event of your CheckBoxes and call `btnPlaceOrder.PerformClick();` to make it recalculate.  You could do the same thing for the RadioButtons...

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons can only have a single button selected at a time in a container. In this case it appears that the GroupBox is the container. If you had several groups of radio buttons you could use GroupBox as a container and have one radio button selected in each GroupBox. So, you cannot set all the radio buttons checked property to true.

In your `btnPlaceOrder_Click` the sender can not posibly be a radio button. The sender is the button that was clicked to run the event code.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Find the radio button that is selected
        RadioButton rButton = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked == true);

        switch (rButton.Text)
        {
            case "Hamburger - $6.95":
                subTotal = 6.95m;
                break;
            case "Pizza - $5.95":
                subTotal = 5.95m;
                break;
            case "Salad - $4.95":
                subTotal = 4.95m;
                break;
        }

        //Add code to handle Add-on items
        //For example - The first check box is "Add Onions" - $0.50
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
            subTotal += .5m;

        lblSubTotal.Text = subTotal.ToString();
        decimal tax = subTotal * .0775m;
        lblTax.Text = tax.ToString();
        decimal total = subTotal + tax;
        lblTotal.Text = total.ToString();
    }
```